# Why is Facebook no longer showing posts from my page to my followers' news feeds?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

Until two weeks ago, each time I posted to my company's Facebook Page wall (via my web app) it would appear in our follower's news feeds.

Now, it's not. But if I manually create a post, it does.

Can anyone shed some light as to why?

I've been using the FbGraph ruby gem like so:

`FbGraph::Page.new(page_id).feed!(options)`

Comment: check if your application has not been blacklisted, it could happen if some people have reported it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a transient issue with the API, or a new bug Facebook introduced with their latest code deployment.  If the issue is reproducible, then log it as a bug with Facebook.